# tools for developing RESTful web services

Tags: http, rest, service

What tools are recommended to aid in developing RESTful web services? For instance, a good front end for manually calling REST APIs, and a TCP/IP or HTTP monitoring tool seem like good starting points. I am looking for specific product recommendations. OS X recommendations would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I use Poster (a FireFox plugin) for manually calling REST web services:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691

(I find the UI is difficult to work with and would like something better.)

Answer (score 2):

- Use the browser of your choice to test your urls. Ideally a restful service can be consumed by any browser.
- For monitoring I'd use either [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Fiddler is definetly easier.

**Edit**

For posts, and the other verbs you can use Fiddler as well to submit the requests. As for handling the application/json, I would use fiddler to look at the results, I'm sure you could define a handler to handle the app/json mimetype but I don't know how to go about that off the top of my head.

Comment: Can you use a browser for verbs other than GET?

Comment: Another problem with the browser is that it opens the open file/save file dialog for URLs that return contentType: application/json. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There is a WcfTestClient included with VS2008 here:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe"

It allows you to explore web services and make calls to them.

Fiddler is also good, as already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/) for basic smoke testing of the various output types and verbs.

You can use [REDbot](http://REDbot.org/about/) to find a lot of subtle issues.

Answer (score 0):

- [rest-client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) - java app, quite mature
- [RestClient](http://rest-client.heroku.com/rdoc/) - ruby DSL, very handy
- [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) - another java app, HTTP proxy, monitor reverse proxy (paid)

Answer (score 0):

[soapUI](http://www.soapui.org) (the free version) has always been very useful for me. It handles REST webservices too - see the examples in the getting started section.